# Passing the data from AngularJs Service to Controller and Controller to Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services, angular-controller

Currently I am able to pass the value from the AngularJS Service to Angular Controller, But Now I am doing some calculation in one controller and now I want to pass it to another controller , Can you please help me

- Service Name : detailService
- Controller 1 : FromService
- Controller 2 : BarCtrl
- In the below Code I am getting the Values from detailService to
  FromService Controller
- And In the FromService Controller I am evaluating the value for Array
  **$scope.valuesSendToGraph**

I wanted to send this $scope.valuesSendToGraph to BarCtrl Controller , Can you please help me , How to approach this Problem

**AngularJS Code**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ["chart.js"]);
app.service('detailService', function($http, $filter, $q) {
  return {
    getInfo: function() {
      return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'myjson.json'
      }).then(function(response) {
        msoResponseArray = response.data;
        var passByCompanyArray = [];
        var failByCompanyArray = [];
        var wipByCompanyArray = [];
        var releasenameArray = [];
        var totalCountArray = [];
        var fullArray = [];

        msoResponseArray.forEach(function(item) {
          releasenameArray.push(item.executions[0].cycleName);
        });

        msoResponseArray.forEach(function(item) {
          /* Filtering the Items Which are Passed*/
          passByCompany = $filter('filter')(item.executions, function(
            inputs) {
            if ((inputs.executedBy == 'a' || inputs.executedBy == 'b' || inputs.executedBy == 'c' || inputs.executedBy == 'd') && inputs.executionStatus == '1') return inputs;

          });
          passByCompanyArray.push(passByCompany.length);
          //passByCompanyArray.unshift(item.executions[0].cycleName);
          failByCompany = $filter('filter')(item.executions, function(
            inputs) {
            if ((inputs.executedBy == 'a' || inputs.executedBy == 'b' || inputs.executedBy == 'c' || inputs.executedBy == 'd') && inputs.executionStatus == '2') return inputs;
          });
          failByCompanyArray.push(failByCompany.length);
          //failByCompanyArray.unshift(item.executions[0].cycleName);

          wipByCompany = $filter('filter')(item.executions, function(
            inputs) {
            if ((inputs.executedBy == 'a' || inputs.executedBy == 'b' || inputs.executedBy == 'c' || inputs.executedBy == 'd') && inputs.executionStatus == '3') return inputs;

          });
          wipByCompanyArray.push(wipByCompany.length);
          //wipByCompanyArray.unshift(item.executions[0].cycleName);

        });
        return $q.when([releasenameArray, passByCompanyArray, failByCompanyArray, wipByCompanyArray]);
      })
    }


  }
});
```

```
app.controller('FromService', function($scope, detailService) {
  detailService.getInfo().then(function(data) {
    $scope.newvalue = data;
    $scope.releasename = data[0];
    $scope.passCount = data[1];
    $scope.failCount = data[2];
    $scope.wipCount = data[3];

    function sumValue(arr) {
      var total = 0;
      arr.forEach(function(element) {
        total += element;
      })
      return total;
    }
    var sumPassCount = sumValue($scope.passCount);
    var sumFailCount = sumValue($scope.failCount);
    var sumWipCount = sumValue($scope.wipCount);
    $scope.valuesSendToGraph = [sumPassCount, sumFailCount, sumWipCount];
    console.log($scope.valuesSendToGraph);


    $scope.fullArray = $scope.releasename.map(function(item, i) {
      return {
        releasename: item,
        passCount: $scope.passCount[i],
        failCount: $scope.failCount[i],
        wipCount: $scope.wipCount[i]
      }
    });
    console.log($scope.fullArray);
  });
});
```

```
app.config(function(ChartJsProvider) {
  // Configure all charts
  ChartJsProvider.setOptions({
    colors: ['#803690', '#00ADF9', '#DCDCDC', '#46BFBD', '#FDB45C', '#949FB1', '#4D5360'],
    defaultFont: 'Ve'


  });
  // Configure all doughnut charts
  ChartJsProvider.setOptions('doughnut', {
    cutoutPercentage: 60
  });
  ChartJsProvider.setOptions('bubble', {
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false
    }
  });
});
```

```
app.controller('BarCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.labels = ['Passed', 'Failed', 'WIP'];
  $scope.series = ['Regression'];

  $scope.data = [
    $scope.valuesSendToGraph
  ];
});
```

Comment: How are the two controllers arranged on the DOM? Are they on parent and child elements or are they on sibling elements?

Comment: They are in the different DIV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am doing some calculation in one controller and now I want to pass it to another controller

I strongly recommend you do move all calculations to service. Controller is responsible to bind data with view.

> I wanted to send this $scope.valuesSendToGraph to BarCtrl Controller

Since Service is singleton, you can store `valuesSendToGraph` in service and load it from other controller

---

If you still want to send `valuesSendToGraph` content from controller to controller and they have the same level, you can use `$broadcast` on root level, for example:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('values', $scope.valuesSendToGraph);
```

In `BarCtrl` call:

```
$scope.$on('values', function(event, data) {
  $scope.valuesSendToGraph = data;
});
```

Be sure that you call `$scope.$on('values',` before `$rootScope.$broadcast`

Comment: Thanks Maxim , I will try to use the best approach as you said, I will try to have the logic in Service only. Now If i want to derive the array , Do i have to create separate function in the Service